# Joomla Control Panel gives error everything else is working

Tags: php, joomla

Joomla 3.9.13, php 7.3.9, MySQL 5.7.19
All my content is up and running
I can access everything except the control panel, when I click on control panel I get error 500. I have no warning and the database is up to date. All my folders are writable.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it fresh joomla instalation ? 
Can you try to change PHP version 7.2 ?

Comment: Joomla support questions are always welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is a indicator something is missconfigured.

please try to switch to php 7.2

more importantly recheck your access and error log of your web server. Please post it also so you can get better help

if you switched to ssl/https change it in the configuration.php back to non ssl

if you have changed .htaccess, disable the .htaccess to check if the error is gone.

more on help you cannot get if you do not share your logs.